# Authenticate at subscription level using Azure SDK

Tags: c#, azure, sdk, subscription

I'm trying to get a list of App Services from a subscription so that I can filter staging sites and delete them using the Azure SDK.  I'm running into the issue of not authenticating properly or not being able to see any resources on the subscription.

I have the "Owner" role on the subscription so I should have total access to the subscription and its resources however when trying to follow Microsoft's docs on authenticating (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication) **I can't seem to find a way to authenticate at the subscription level**.

Here's the code I have:

```
                var azurecreds = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory
                   .FromServicePrincipal(
                       "???",  //client ID
                       "???",  //client secret
                       "have this",  //tenant ID
                       AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

                var azure = Azure
                    .Configure()
                    .Authenticate(azurecreds)
                    .WithSubscription("have this");    //subscription ID

                //attempts with hard-coded values but not working
                var appServicePlans = azure.AppServices.AppServicePlans.List();
                var appServicePlans2 = azure.WebApps.List();
                var appServicePlans2 = azure.AppServices.AppServicePlans.ListByResourceGroup("Staging");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are following this document : [Authenticate with token credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/azure/sdk/authentication#authenticate-with-token-credentials)

So , as per the above document , you must have created a service principal using this command :

```
 az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth
```

After you have create this service principal , you will get the below details :

[image]

From the above picture you have to copy the `ClientID`, `Client Secret`, `TenantID` and `SubscriptionId`. After you have taken a note of these mentioned details , you can put the same in the code .

```
var azurecreds = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory  
.FromServicePrincipal(  
"ClientID copied from the above step", //client ID  
"Client Secret Copied from the above step", //client secret  
"have this", //tenant ID  
AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

  

var azure = Azure  
.Configure()  
.Authenticate(azurecreds)  
.WithSubscription("have this"); //subscription ID

  

//attempts with hard-coded values but not working  
var appServicePlans = azure.AppServices.AppServicePlans.List();  
var appServicePlans2 = azure.WebApps.List();  
var appServicePlans2 = azure.AppServices.AppServicePlans.ListByResourceGroup("Staging");
```

Comment: Awesome, that kind-of worked as it's returning objects that I recognize on a subscription!  The issue now is that it's working on the wrong subscription.  When running the code on the correct subscription, it's saying I'm unauthorized.  Would I need to create a separate service principle on the other subscription then and if so, how could I specify the other subscription when creating it?

Comment: You can use : `az account set -s` "Your subscription which you want to set for creating the Service Principal"

Comment: That resolved the subscription issue as my code can now list and filter the staging sites I wanted to obtain.  Thank you so much for your help!